# Grails: applying annotations to property accessors instead of field

Tags: grails, properties, annotations, grails-2.0

In Grails, is it possible to apply annotations to properties' accessors instead of (or in addition to) its field, without explicitly defining the accessors?

If so, what version of Grails is required?

e.g., I'd like something like the following (using a fake syntax that uses specific labels to determine what to apply annotations to):

```
class C {
    field:
    @A1
    getter:
    @A2
    getter:
    @A3
    accessors:
    @A4
    all:
    @A5
    String p
}
```

Comment: @sudhir please be careful when claiming that something can't be done. At a minimum say that you're not aware that something is possible unless you know for sure.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith - he wants to put the annotation on accessors (getters)  without explicitly defining the getter in his class. is it really possible ?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a property in a POGO like a Grails domain class, the Groovy compiler rewrites it as a private field with a getter and a setter, but only if there's no scope modifier (`public`/`protected`/etc.)

This is convenient because if you later want to add logic or calculations when setting and/or getting the value, you can add your own getter and/or setter method and the compiler will only generate methods that aren't already explicitly defined. Java classes will have been using the getters and setters already, so this doesn't affect existing clients or require recompiling.

You can see by decompiling your domain class that the Groovy compiler moves any annotations defined on properties to the fields, so for example with this domain class

```
class Thing {
   @Foo
   String name
}
```

you'll see code similar to this in the decompiled code:

```
@Foo
private String name;

public String getName() {
   return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name
}
```

Many frameworks will access field annotations or accessor annotations, so often this works without any additional configuration, but it depends on  the framework or code that's reading the annotations.

Comment: I already knew that Groovy creates implicit accessors for properties, if the accessors aren't already defined.  I want to be able to apply the annotation @Foo to getName() by just annotating the property name, instead of having to annotate an explicitly written getName() method with @ Foo.  Is that possible?  I don't see a way to do that in your answer.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no direct way to influence how the accessors are defined. You could probably rework things with an AST transform or other compilation customizer, which wouldn't be simple but would separate the code from your annotated classes.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith that's what I meant when I said its not possible, obviously he has option to go for AST etc, but i guess that's not he is looking for, he probably wants to know if there's any built in way to do this and have annotations on generated accessors rather then fields.

Comment: Any recommendations for how to do this? Can groovyc (or something else in the Grails build) process annotations? Or does it just pass them through to javac? If it maintains the order of annotations, then I could make @ GetterAnnotations, @ SetterAnnotations, @ FieldAnnotations, etc., and have all of the annotations after one of the above (but before another of the above) apply to the corresponding part of the property. I'd also have to prevent Groovy from adding the annotations to the field, or remove the annotations from the field if I can't prevent Groovy from adding them.